# Error while partitioning the parquet file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, parquet, partitioning

I have searched online a lot but for partitionBy example I see same example of country or gender.Can anyone say if a column name Brand having elements like- H & M, Zara , Tommy Hilfiger can be partitioned in scala?And the other columns being description, price,index all in CSV format.Please suggest if i have to do something additionally to csv file before converting it into parquet file
`data.write.partitionBy("Brand").format("parquet").save(path)`
Any help would be so appreciated.Thankyou

Comment: Can you put the error in your question?

Comment: error: Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
 
error:Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/path

Comment: check the distinct values of Brand col to see if there are null or leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Also, check if the job has permission to create a folder in that path.

Comment: okay so it does not have to with the spaces,& and the number of words in the brand for using partitionBy?

Comment: Some special chars might cause that issue but spaces in between words should be fine. Numbers are fine.

Comment: @morfious902002 Oh.Thanks a lot for replying really appreciate it!